# How to extract a specific element from EXIF photographic metadata?

Tags: import, image-processing, replacement

It's now possible to import photographs into *Mathematica* and import the EXIF data at the same time:

```
i = Import["ExampleData/coneflower.jpg", "ImageWithExif"]
```

[image: coneflower]

You can now look at all the metadata:

```
Options[i, MetaInformation]
```

> {MetaInformation -> {"Exif" -> {"ImageDescription" -> "          ", 
>       "Make" -> "NIKON", "Model" -> "E950", "Orientation" -> 1, 
>       "XResolution" -> 300, "YResolution" -> 300, 
>        "ResolutionUnit" -> 2, 
>        "Software" -> "Adobe Photoshop CS3 Macintosh", 
>        "DateTime" -> "2008:08:19 11:29:05", etc...

So how would I extract - say - the exposure time ("ExposureTime")? I was trying something like this:

```
"ExposureTime" /. Options[i, MetaInformation] ...
```

but I don't know enough about the structure of the stored metainformation. Can you do this without knowing that structure?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Does this do want you want?

```
Cases[Options[i, MetaInformation], 
 HoldPattern["ExposureTime" -> ___], Infinity]
```

or even simpler because it is `Rule`s all the way down:

```
Cases[Options[i], HoldPattern["ExposureTime" -> ___], Infinity]
```

> ```
> {"ExposureTime" -> 1/65}
> ```

All-in-one:

```
With[{wanted = "ExposureTime"}, 
  wanted /. Cases[Options[i], HoldPattern[wanted -> ___], Infinity]] //
  N
```

Comment: Thanks, yes, that seems to work... So `N[Last[Last[
   Cases[Options[f], HoldPattern["ExposureTime" -> ___], Infinity]]]]` is what I need?! Looks a tad clunky...

Comment: @cormullion I´d go for a something like
`With[{wanted = "ExposureTime"}, 
  wanted /. Cases[Options[i], HoldPattern[wanted -> ___], Infinity]
  ] // N`

Comment: @cormullion but yes, there ought to be something cleaner - let´s wait for better approaches

Answer (score 7):

Here is something based on `FilterRules` and using your post of Exif metadata format.

**FilterRules**

```
FilterRules["Exif" /. (MetaInformation /. Options[i, MetaInformation]), "XResolution"]
```

> {"XResolution" -> 300}

There may be more elegant ways to extract the rules which form part of `MetaInformation`, I await them with interest.

This unpacks nested sets of rules:

```
FilterRules[ Options[i, MetaInformation] //. {_ -> z_} -> z, "XResolution"]
```

> {"XResolution" -> 300}

**OptionValue**

Here is an interesting alternative which does require some knowledge of the structure of the `MetaInformation` but is otherwise nicely concise.

```
OptionValue[Options[i, MetaInformation], MetaInformation -> "Exif" -> "XResolution"]
```

> 300

Comment: +1 ...but you need more information on the structure of `MetaInformation`...

Comment: @YvesKlett Fair point :) I've had a go at finding so something less dependent on the form of `MetaInformation`.

Comment: Uhhh... wicked ;-)

Comment: Excellent - getting concise-r, but still it's not as slick as I would have expected from *Mathematica*... :)

Comment: @cormullion Yes, I get what you are saying :)

Answer (score 1):

The earlier answers stopped working for Mathematica 11+. In Mathematica 10 and earlier, the [`MetaInformation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MetaInformation) was a nested list of rules:

```
$VersionNumber
i = Import["ExampleData/coneflower.jpg","ImageWithExif"];
Options[i, MetaInformation] //Short
```

> 10.3
>
> {MetaInformation->{Exif->{ImageDescription->          ,<<37>>,SceneType->1}}}

In Mathematica 11+, the [`MetaInformation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MetaInformation) is now an [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association). This means that the previous approaches no longer work:

```
$VersionNumber
 i = Import["ExampleData/coneflower.jpg","ImageWithExif"];
 Quiet @ Check[
  OptionValue[Options[i], MetaInformation -> "Exif" -> "ExposureTime"],
  $Failed
]

Cases[Options[i], HoldPattern["ExposureTime" -> ___], Infinity]
```

> 11.3
>
> $Failed
>
> {}

Instead, you will need to extract information from an association. If you don't know the structure of the association you can use [`Keys`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Keys) to investigate:

```
meta = OptionValue[Options[i], MetaInformation];
meta //Keys
```

> {"Exif"}

Then:

```
meta["Exif"] //Keys
```

> {"Make", "Model", "Orientation", "XResolution", "YResolution", 
>   "ResolutionUnit", "Software", "DateTime", "YCbCrPositioning", "ExposureTime", "FNumber", "ExposureProgram", "ISOSpeedRatings", "ExifVersion", 
>   "DateTimeOriginal", "DateTimeDigitized", "ComponentsConfiguration", 
>   "CompressedBitsPerPixel", "ExposureBiasValue", "MaxApertureValue", 
>   "MeteringMode", "LightSource", "FlashInfo", "FocalLength", "FlashpixVersion", 
>   "ColorSpace", "PixelXDimension", "PixelYDimension", "InteroperabilityIndex", 
>   "InteroperabilityVersion", "FileSource", "SceneType"}

Now we see "ExposureTime". So:

```
meta["Exif", "ExposureTime"]
```

> Quantity[1/65, "Seconds"]

Answer (score 0):

Just a note that Mathematica has since made the importing of Exif metadata easier:

```
Import["ExampleData/coneflower.jpg", "ExposureTime"]
```

> Quantity[Rational[1,65],"Seconds"]

(This displays nicely as `1/65 s` in the front-end.)

This is a bit confusing because `"ExposureTime"` isn't listed in the list of possible things to import:

```
Import["ExampleData/coneflower.jpg","Elements"]
```

> {BitDepth, CameraTopOrientation, Channels, ColorMap, ColorProfileData, ColorSpace, Data, DateTime, Exif, FlashUsed, GeoPosition, GPSDateTime, Graphics, Image, ImageSize, IPTC, RawData, RawExif, RawIPTC, RawXMP, RedEyeCorrection, Summary, Thumbnail, XMP}

However, in the [docs for JPEG](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/JPEG.html), under "Scope", it says that any Exif tags can be directly imported.