# Putting large amounts of data inside a self-contained Manipulate

Tags: manipulate

This is half tip, half question. If one tries to put a large amount of data inside the Initialization:>(code) part of a Manipulate, as one may be compelled to do in a Demonstration or where one wants to create a self-contained CDF document, I find that the Front End gets bogged down trying to format the input.  One way around this that I've discovered is to embed the data inside a Raster.  Thus:

```
embedded=Framed@Graphics[Raster[bigdata]] (*Framed is so you can see it*)
```

The visual output is meaningless.  But ... you can then cut and paste the Framed object inside your initialization block and get the data out easily

```
Manipuate[f[data,n],{n,0,1},
Initialization:>(embedded=(*paste cut framed graphic here*);
data=embedded[[1,1,1]])
]
```

So far as I can tell, this works.  But it depends on an abuse of Raster and Graphics.  Does anyone have suggestions about alternative means of putting large amounts of data inside a Manipulate?

Comment: +1 Great question, had similar problems. Perhaps one can also use `Compress`.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE, Seth!

Comment: @Ajasja Which is not dissimilar, since `Compress` is effectively used by images.

Comment: I second Yves. Welcome, Seth!

Comment: Would you mind supplying some `bigdata` to play around with?

Comment: Related: http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/632/ and http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/633/57

Comment: Rojo showed me a trick using `string=Interpretation["string", Evaluate@string]` that I think would work here, possibly in unison with `Compress` if needed.  I'd rather let him write about it however.

Comment: I think you can use a self contained SaveDefinition showed by Leonid [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6580284/1363677)

Answer (score 7):

Since we were talking about [EXIF information](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15772/131) yesterday (any compression to be added on top):

```
data = Image[Circle[] // Graphics, 
  MetaInformation -> {"The Data" -> 
     ExampleData[{"Text", "OriginOfSpecies"}]}]
MetaInformation /. Options[data]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Sorry for blowing up the thread, but this also works nicely, [Matryoshka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matryoshka_doll) style:
[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Clever. Any known restrictions to EXIF data size?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries good question... from the *Mathematica* point of view it is simply an option, so internally probably no explicit limit?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries also this is `MetaInformation` and just derived from the EXIF thread. It might be interesting to check if `Export` and re-`Import` with EXIF data works. See  also this one: [What is the maximum size of JPEG metadata?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3248946)